# Split Polyline QGIS - Too Many Resultant Features

Tags: qgis, line, splitting

I'm trying to split a single polyline into 2 polylines (I have lines that loop back on themselves, and I need to split each one into two lines: one for going, and one for coming back).

When I use the Split Feature tool in Advanced Digitizing, it takes the single polyline feature, and splits it into 66 different polylines, with what looks like anywhere between 2 and 5 vertices per polyline.

I was hoping someone could point out what I'm doing wrong, or what a better feature/tool might be to take a single polyline feature and split it into 2 (and only 2) parts at a given point that I manually choose.

I'm using QGIS 2.8.2 running on a Mac 10.10.4.

Comment: Split Feature works as it should here in QGIS 2.12 under Ubuntu 14.04 and I don't remember it ever not working in any previous versions, Win or Linux. However, you don't appear to be doing anything wrong, perhaps the problem is to do with running QGIS on a Mac? N.